# Adding SUM's to SQL query makes it last 7 minutes instead of 3 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query (generated by Doctrine ORM):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    s0_.id AS id0, 
    SUM(
        s1_.price * s1_.amount * (1 + s1_.tax + s1_.retax)
    ) AS sclr1, 
    s0_.id AS id2 
FROM 
    fr_order s0_ 
    INNER JOIN fr_store s2_ ON s0_.store_id = s2_.id 
    LEFT JOIN fr_orderline s1_ ON s0_.id = s1_.order_id AND (s1_.rejected = 0) 
    LEFT JOIN fr_order_provider_warn s3_ ON s0_.id = s3_.order_id 
WHERE 
    s0_.state >= 3
GROUP BY 
    s0_.id, 
    s0_.date, 
    s0_.shipment_limit_date, 
    s0_.state, 
    s0_.state_changed_date, 
    s0_.received, 
    s0_.shipment_cost, 
    s0_.username, 
    s0_.notes, 
    s0_.user_id, 
    s0_.store_id, 
    s0_.storedata_id, 
    s3_.id, 
    s3_.createdDate, 
    s3_.comments, 
    s3_.order_id 
ORDER BY 
    s0_.id DESC 
LIMIT 
    10 OFFSET 0
```

It takes approximately 3 seconds to run in an 18000 rows table (`fr_order`). I need to get a couple more of summed values so I modified the DQL and Doctrine added the following lines to the SELECT, after the first SUM:

```
SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount) AS sclr2, 
SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1_.tax) AS sclr3, 
SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1_.retax) AS sclr4,
```

Now, the query takes 7 minutes, so the application becomes unusable. Is this performance drop normal? I'm using MySQL 5 as the database server.

**EDIT**

I have ran an `EXPLAIN` on both queries. The result is the same:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                        | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s0_   | ALL    | IDX_F4A5D9B092A811   | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                       | 16823 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s2_   | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY              | 4       | companydb_new.s0_.store_id |     1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s1_   | ref    | IDX_252BF9D78D9F6D38 | IDX_252BF9D78D9F6D38 | 5       | companydb_new.s0_.id       |     3 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s3_   | ref    | IDX_20FC41F28D9F6D38 | IDX_20FC41F28D9F6D38 | 5       | companydb_new.s0_.id       |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

And this are the indexes for the biggest tables, `fr_oder` (`s0_`) and `fr_orderline` (`s1_`):

```
mysql> show indexes from fr_order;
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| fr_order |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id           | A         |       14986 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fr_order |          1 | IDX_F4A5D9B092A811 |            1 | store_id     | A         |          71 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fr_order |          1 | IDX_F4A5D9AAD1D029 |            1 | storedata_id | A         |         405 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fr_order |          1 | IDX_F4A5D9A76ED395 |            1 | user_id      | A         |          86 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

mysql> show indexes from fr_orderline;
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| fr_orderline |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | id          | A         |      114799 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fr_orderline |          1 | IDX_252BF9D7A53A8AA  |            1 | provider_id | A         |          88 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fr_orderline |          1 | IDX_252BF9D78D9F6D38 |            1 | order_id    | A         |       28699 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fr_orderline |          1 | IDX_252BF9D72989F1FD |            1 | invoice_id  | A         |       28699 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

From the EXPLAIN output, it seems that MySQL is not using `s0_` index... I've tried regenerating all the tables indexes but the result is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: What indexes exist on the tables? What output do you get from `EXPLAIN` for the two different queries?

Comment: EXPLAIN statment would be helpful! Also, details of indexes on your table(s) ?

Comment: I wonder what perf gains you get if you reduce the `GROUP BY` to just fields necessary to compute the `SUM( orderline.etc )` values then `JOIN` on `fr_order` and `fr_order_provider_warn` in an outer-query.

Comment: I wonder if all those fields in the `GROUP BY` are needed when you only select `s0_.id` without an aggregate function.  If you only `GROUP BY s0_.id` then you can probably also remove the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: My VPN connection just went down and I can't connect to the office server. I'll post the EXPLAIN and the indexes as soon as it's back... Also, I'll have a look at the DQL to see why Doctrine is adding so many GROUP BY fields.

Comment: Does the performance hit happen only when all three extra selects are added, or can you narrow it down to one in particular? Or perhaps any one of the three causes the problem?

Comment: I'll test them one by one and I'll let you know, thanks!

Comment: @brabster, I've realized that, if I leave 3 or less SUM operations (instead 4), the performance is perfect. It doesn't matter which 3 SUM I add, it always runs fast. However, if I leave it with 4 SUM, it's completely unusable. Is it perhaps a MySQL limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming s0_.id and s3_.id are the primary key for the  table  s0_ and s3_

```
  SELECT 
  DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0, 
  SUM( s1_.price * s1_.amount * (1 + s1_.tax + s1_.retax) ) AS sclr1, 
  SUM( s1_.price * s1_.amount) AS sclr2, 
  SUM( s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1_.tax) AS sclr3, 
  SUM( s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1_.retax) AS sclr4,
  s0_.id AS id2 
  FROM  fr_order s0_ 
  INNER JOIN fr_store s2_ ON s0_.store_id = s2_.id 
  LEFT JOIN fr_orderline s1_ ON s0_.id = s1_.order_id 
          AND (s1_.rejected = 0) 
  LEFT JOIN fr_order_provider_warn s3_ ON s0_.id = s3_.order_id 
  WHERE s0_.state >= 3
  GROUP BY s0_.id, s3_.id, 

  ORDER BY s0_.id DESC 
  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

You don't need  distinct for grouped values and you don't need  others column of a table if you group by for a primary key of this table

be sure you hava proper index on the involved  table  .. for this could be use  some composite indexes

```
  for table  s1_ a composite index  on  ( order_id,rejected price, amount, tax, retax)

  for table s0_  a composite index  on ( state, store_id, id)

  for table s3 _ a index  on ( order_id )
```